# Array group in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, sum

I have the following array data:

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [schoolBin] => 110140014570
        [schoolName] => школа-лицей № 66
        [users] => 30
        [tb0306_tb0301_id] => 514725
        [tb0306_tb3002_id] => 17
        [tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers] => 14
        [point] => 4
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [schoolBin] => 110140014570
        [schoolName] => школа-лицей № 66
        [users] => 30
        [tb0306_tb0301_id] => 514725
        [tb0306_tb3002_id] => 18
        [tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers] => 11
        [point] => 4
    )
```

So, i have many `tb0306_tb0301_id` from one `schoolBin`, and `tb0306_tb0301_id` has many `tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers` of `tb0306_tb3002_id`. So i need to sum all `tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers` of for all `tb0306_tb0301_id` of one `schoolBin` and i have many `schoolBin`, so i need to do the process for all `schoolBin`.

Tried the code:

```
        $results = array();

    foreach ($schoolResults as $schoolResult) {
        $schoolBin = $schoolResult->schoolBin;

        if (isset($results[$schoolBin])) {
            $results[$schoolBin][] = $schoolResult;
        } else {
            $results[$schoolBin] = array($schoolResult);
        }
    }
```

But could not sum `tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers` for one `tb0306_tb0301_id`.

Any helps guys!

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to `sum` the `tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers` for `tb0306_tb0301_id` of `schoolBin`. I use @ to ingnore the worning for uninitial value.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($schoolResults as $schoolResult) {
    @$result[$schoolResult->schoolBin][$schoolResult->tb0306_tb0301_id] += $schoolResult->tb0306_countOfCorrectAnswers
}
```